# How to write a junit Test Case of a function which is reading a file?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, junit, mockito

Here is my code :

```
 public String getFile() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder fileURI = new StringBuilder(locationName);
    fileURI.append(keyName);
    S3ObjectInputStream ts = null;
    ts = (S3ObjectInputStream) s3Services.getResourceStream(fileURI.toString());
    String time;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ts))) {
        time = reader.readLine();
    }
    return time;
}
```

I am trying to mock this function, I am not sure how to Mock the InputStreamReader object :

```
 public void testgetTs() throws IOException {
    Mockito.mock(Service.class);
    StringBuilder fileURI = new StringBuilder("test");
    fileURI.append("/");
    fileURI.append("testFile.txt");
    S3ObjectInputStream ts = null;
    Mockito.when(s3Services.getResourceStream(fileURI.toString())).thenReturn(ts);
    service.getTime();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock out any external resources, in your case that's hard because you are creating all your resources internally and therefore your method does not have a [single responsibility][1], but many.  To properly unit test you would need to break it into units, inject parameters and mock out resources:

**Unit 1, *Building the file name***

```
StringBuilder fileURI = new StringBuilder(locationName);
fileURI.append(keyName);
```

Here you want to be able to test what the result of setting `locationName` and `keyName` to different things is.  i.e. something like `FileUriBuilder(locationName, keyName).getString()`

**Unit 2, *Getting the resource stream***

```
S3ObjectInputStream ts = null;
ts = (S3ObjectInputStream) s3Services.getResourceStream(fileURI.toString());
```

Here you want to mock out `s3Services` and test that `getResourceStream()` is called with the expected value.  If you are injecting `FileUriBuilder` you'll want to mock that.

**Unit 3, *Reading the stream***

```
String time;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ts))) {
    time = reader.readLine();
}
return time;
```

Here you want to mock out `S3ObjectInputStream` and make sure the correct methods on it are called and that when it returns something that this unit reports it as expected.

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle#:~:text=The%20single%2Dresponsibility%20principle%20(SRP,functionality%2C%20which%20it%20should%20encapsulate